# Importing contacts into Civicrm

Tags: import, fields, custom

I am importing 350 contacts into Civi. This [post](https://www.cividesk.com/blog/post/importing-contacts-civicrm-be-sure-include-import-identifier-just-case) says that you should always include an import identifier. I don't have admin access so I cannot create a custom field set. I was going to identify the contacts by tagging them all. Alternatively, Civi includes a contact source field. Could I include a value for contact source in the CSV file? I will also tag the imports.

Answer (score 1):

These are all valid options!  I never use a custom field for this; I use tags or the contact source field.  The "external identifier" field is often useful for this - I'll tag contacts from a certain location with their ID from that source prefaced by an acronym for that source.

As someone who works daily with data migrations, I rarely *need* to do any of these things if I'm the one who might have to deal with mistakes.  Using advanced logging is good enough; if it's only 350 contacts, it's probably enough to just go by creation date.

That said, I highly recommend that people who don't do this regularly tag their contacts or use the Source field :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I appreciate the response.